# How to deliver a message from an activity that called fragment to that fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have `ActivityA extends ActionBarActivity` that starts `FragmentB` which is started immediately after `ActivityA` starts (in `ActivityA.onCreate ()` with default a parameter `param`). I have several other `Fragment`s that can be started by `ActivityA`, and hence this design.

In `ActivityA`, I have implemented the `SearchView` tied to the search button on the action bar, by following [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html). I am able to get upto the point where I get the search text, but now, I need to update the `param` in `FragmentB` based on the search query in `ActivityA` (or simply just send the search query to `FragmentB` and make it do the search asynchronously). How do I do send the parameter to `FragmentB` which I know is running? I.e.,  How do I pass `param` from `ActivityA.handleIntent (Intent intent)` to `FragmentB`?

Is this good design in the first place? Should I move the search code infrastructure into the fragment? If so, the other fragments that will be started within `ActivityA` context will not have access to the search infrastructure.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: @biegleux, I have seen that link. I want to be sure that it won't re-instate `FragmentB` or cause my  back stack to go haywire? Is that the only way?

Comment: You can be sure and no, it is not the only way. You can use http://square.github.io/otto/ or https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @biegleux: Most excellent. Thank you. I know why I come here for these questions... I wish I had known about event bus earlier!

Comment: @Sonny Exactly my words some time ago.